# How to display lines from mongoDB with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new with js.
So, I want to display lines from a table of my mongoDB.

This is my code:

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var timestamp = require('./plugins/timestamp');
var toString = require('./plugins/to-string');
var alphanumeric = require('./plugins/alphanumeric');

var async = require('async');
var moment = require('moment');
var S = require('string');
var _ = require('lodash');

var car = require('./car');


var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  make: {type: String, trim: true, required: true},
  model: {type: String, trim: true, required: true},
  seats: Number,
  plateNumber: {type: String, unique: true, trim: true, alphanumeric: true},
});

var cars = mongoose.model('car');

var query = car.find(null);
query.limit(3);


query.exec(function (err, cars {
  if (err) { throw err; }

  var c;
  for (var i = 0, l = c.length; i < l; i++) {
    c = c[i];
    console.log('------------------------------');
    console.log('ID : ' + c._id);
    console.log('Make : ' + c.make);
    console.log('model : ' + c.model);
    console.log('seats : ' + c.seats);
    console.log('------------------------------');
  }
});
```

the problem, I think, is in 'cars' cause I don't know how to deal with the exec().

anyone can help me please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model can be executed by using callback function or `exec` method.

`exec` returns you the Promise too.

`exec`

```
 .exec(function (err, user) {
      //
  });
```

in your code you have syntax error as you have mismatched the `exec` method

```
var query = car.find({});
query.limit(3);


query.exec(function (err, cars) {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    for (var i=0;i< cars.length; i++) {
        console.log('______________________________');
        console.log('ID : ' + cars[i]._id);
        console.log('Make : ' + cars[i].make);
        console.log('model : ' + cars[i].model);
        console.log('seats : ' + cars[i].seats);
        console.log('------------------------------');
    }
});
```

Comment: and you know what is the meaning of this?
Schema hasn't been registered for model "car".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

Comment: you need to provide the schema name, your schema name is `schema`, so

`var cars = mongoose.model('car')` should be `var cars = mongoose.model('car', schema);`

Comment: thank you bro, just I can't now, I'm not home,
just I tried that before, and I got this message.
(node:23805) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: i am quite confused you have imported your model `car` and why are declaring your `schema` again in same file ??, Mongoose Promise warning 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: can you send me your email address please?

Comment: can you answer my email please?